# not found utils/context.sol when i import from openzepplin

Tags: importerror, solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

i have copied a contract from openzappline. but when i compile it on remix it gives me the error....that utils/context.sol is not found.

here is the import

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./IERC20.sol";
import "./extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol";
import "../../utils/Context.sol";

contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata {
mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

uint256 private _totalSupply;

string private _name;
string private _symbol;
```

Answer (score 2):

`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";`

this should help

The file that's being called is from the root directory, not inside the ERC20 files.

Answer (score 1):

```
import "../../utils/Context.sol";
```

This line tries to import the file `Context.sol` from "utils" folder located "two folders up" relative to the folder where your `ERC20` contract is located.

Easiest solution in this context (where no other contract imports the `Context.sol`) is to copy-paste the [Context.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Context.sol) to a reachable location (e.g. to the same folder as your `ERC20`) and change the import path (e.g. to `import "./Context.sol"`).

Comment: when i delete context.sol it shows same error for this line                                                         import "./extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol";

Comment: Then you don't have the `IERC20Metadata.sol` file in folder `extensions` relative to your root folder. Follow the same guide from my answer but with the `IERC20Metadata.sol` file

Comment: so i have to put this file in remix within same folder?

Comment: @FSO That's correct. Don't forget to change the imports so that they point to the same folder as well.

Comment: where to find ec20detailed?

Comment: @FSO Tip: Search the OpenZeppelin's [GitHub](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC20)

Answer (score 0):

If youre importing an openzeppelin contract ex:
`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";`

make sure to include a GPL-3 licence

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
```

this helped me to get the npm deps in remix